# Unable to configure jsf with spring in jboss

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, jboss

I'm performing migration of project that uses JSP to JSF. I've created a template xhtml page that working properly. The problems began when I've started integration with Spring. As describes [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf-springbeanfaceselresolver) and on this [tutorial](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/will-they-blend-how-to-use-spring-with-jsf-for-resource-bundling/), I need to modify `faces-config.xml` by setting the resolver.

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

With this configuration I should be able to represent messages of message source bean. But, it does not happen. After setting configuration in `faces-config.xml` I'm starting to get the following error when trying to access to the frontend page:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax/faces/context/FacesContext
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    com.accenture.flow.frontend.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:49)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)

...

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContext
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getWebApplicationContext(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:78)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:49)
```

I think that this error is very strange, because `FacesContext` class is located in `jsf-api.jar`, which was loaded when jboss server was starting. 
I've tried to include `jsf-api.jar`and `jsf-impl.jar`in my EAR, then I've tried to import it as a module of jboss, but always getting the same error.

Will appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem by adding

```
<module name="javax.faces.api" />  
<module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
```

to `org.springframework` jboss module in  `jboss-eap-6.3\modules\org\springframework\main\module.xml`